# jquery mobile: when I second time visit the page the pagecreate event fired two times

Tags: jquery-mobile

I try to useing "live" to binding pagecreate event ,but when I second time visit the page pagecreate event fired two times.when I useing "bind" it is normal

---

```
<div data-role="page" name="logAddPage" id="logAddPage">  
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#logAddPage").live("pagecreate",function (){
            alert("pagecreate event fired ...");
        });
    </script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

It is better to remove any listeners before binding it.

```
$("#logAddPage").off("pagecreate");
$("#logAddPage").on("pagecreate", function (e) {
    alert("pagecreate event fired ...");
});
```

Comment: Great answer; You should definitely be marked as correct. @zhengyanan, did this not work for you?

Comment: I was having problems with an ajax form crapping out when submitted a second time and couldn't clearly identify the problem, but this lead me to finding and fixing the problem. You should definitely be marked as correct.

Answer (score 0):

i think you missed one bracket '('

try like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#logAddPage").live("pagecreate",function (){
        alert("pagecreate event fired ...");
    });
</script>
```